# Styling Google Map API's Polylines

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I am using google map api and was wondering if there was anyway of creating a dashed or dotted stroke of a polyline. Would there also be an easy way to create a curved line between two destinations rather than a straight line: the code I currently have draws a straight grey line,

```
polyline = new google.maps.Polyline( { path: route, strokeColor: "#7d7d7d", strokeOpacity: 0.6, strokeWeight: 5 } );
                    polyline.setMap( map );
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What kind of curved line?  You can add `geodesic: true` to your Polyline options, which will draw curved lines showing the shortest distance between two points (taking into account the curvature of the earth), but they only really are noticeable when zoomed out far enough and the line is between two quite far apart longitudes.

Comment: This sounds promising I will try this out thanks, the more important thing for me right now is to get a dashed stroke line instead of solid one, is there any option to do this?

Comment: Thankyou yes this creates a perfect curved line which is brilliant, however still no luck on the dashed stroke

Comment: No, that's a feature that's already been requested that you can vote for: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1800

Comment: Hi this polyline was working fine for me once clicking a button, but now it has suddenly disappeared! I havent cahnged any code t do with the polyline, I was wondering does it have to have a zIndex or could it be under the map? Or do you have to have an eventlistener? I am really puzzled as to where it went or what happened?

Comment: Possibly if you're using the most recent version of the API (3.7), they've changed something which has affected it.  Try setting the v=3.6 parameter in the URL to use the last stable release: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Versioning

Answer (score 9):

Look at my free plugin for curved lines in Google maps, I'ts very basic solution but it gets the job done:
http://curved_lines.overfx.net/